# Does Optane RAID differ than Normal SSD RAID?

Tags: ssd, raid

Is there any difference in having Optane SSDs in RAID 0 in PCIe slots than compared with conventional SSDs in RAID 0? How about RAID 1 or higher? (assuming sufficient PCIe slots)

I will leave it at that for simplicity. However, if you feel it's too broad, you may read on and consider approaching the answer in the following ways:

-------------------------- **Optional** --------------------------

- Is the marginal return to read/write performance better on a per RAID unit basis
  (when compared with conventional SSDS)?
- Are there any synergies that can be utilized with Optane RAID arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Optane memory is orders of magnitude faster then "regular" SSD memory so yes, it will be faster in both RAID0 and RAID1

RAID1 provides for redundancy more then speed, but depending on the environment it could give you a speed boost for reading - but still not comparable to Optane memory.

Optane memory is expected to be quite small (16 & 32 gig capacities), meaning its more useful as a cache then as primary storage in environments where it would be most useful.  Thus you would put Optane memory in front of regular hard drives or SSD's to cache most used systems - this would seem to dovetail well with ZFS filesystems (which can take advantage of this kind of cache), as well as existing and new systems which can use SSD for this purpose.

Comment: So if we set up a RAID0 Optane Cache array, it would have a large performance boost than just 1 Optane SSD?

Comment: I think its to early to tell - this is very new technology and I don't think its readily available yet. Going on the specs from http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/memory-storage/optane-memory/optane-32gb-m-2-80mm.html the performance won't be nearly as fast as hyped initially, so setting up a cache array in RAID0 could give you a performance boost, particularly for writes and heavy read loads.